# Datanucleus-neo4j maven plugin error that already exists

Tags: maven, neo4j, datanucleus, nosql

i'm following Datanucleus - neo4j tutorial.

and successed all steps until i ran maven command ( java:exec )

the error is this.

java:exec

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DataNucleus JPA Tutorial 5.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) > validate @ datanucleus-samples-jpa-tutorial >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) < validate @ datanucleus-samples-jpa-tutorial <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) @ datanucleus-samples-jpa-tutorial ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.880 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-11T19:41:40+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1:java (default-cli) on project datanucleus-samples-jpa-tutorial: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating transactional connection factory: org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(Ljava/io/File;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService; -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

the pom.xml file is like this.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-samples-jdo-tutorial</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>4.0</version>
    <name>DataNucleus AccessPlatform Tutorial for JDO</name>
    <url>http://www.datanucleus.org</url>

    <properties>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-release, 4.9)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-release, 4.1.99)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>[1.2, 1.3)</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- ENABLE THIS FOR Neo4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>[4.0.0-release, 4.9)</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
 </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*.log</include>
                                <include>tutorial.ods</include>
                                <include>tutorial.xls</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${basedir}/testDB</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-release</version>
                <configuration>
                    <api>JDO</api>
                    <persistenceUnitName>Tutorial</persistenceUnitName>
                    <log4jConfiguration>src/main/resources/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Main</mainClass>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <key>log4j.configuration</key>
                            <value>file:src/main/resources/log4j.properties</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

i exactly followed what tutorial said.

i already tried add runtimeline in pom.xml file on

datanucleus-core dependency but i didn't work.

i checked plugins so that maybe they were not imported but

all of them were imported.

so it seems when i run exec:java command, it use plugin maven-plugin1.1

and it fail to load.

another problem is that fail to create transactional connections factory.

i tried to fix these problems but i don't know what to do.

Can anybody help?

=========================================================

these are what i done following what the tutorial said.

1. Edit the datastore details on persistence.xml file at src/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

   ```
   <!-- Tutorial "unit" -->
   <persistence-unit name="Tutorial">
       <class>org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Inventory</class>
       <class>org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Product</class>
       <class>org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Book</class>
       <exclude-unlisted-classes/>
       <properties>
           <!-- ENABLE THESE FOR H2 -->
           <!--<property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:h2:mem:nucleus1"/>-->
           <!--<property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>-->
           <!--<property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName" value="sa"/>-->
           <!--<property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword" value=""/>-->
           <!--<property name="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="h2"/>-->

           <!-- ENABLE THESE FOR HSQLDB -->
           <!--property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:nucleus1"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName" value="sa"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword" value=""/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="hsql"/-->

           <!-- ENABLE THESE FOR MySQL/MariaDB -->
           <!-- Change the "nucleus" to your database name, and the user/password -->
           <!--property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/nucleus?useServerPrepStmts=false"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName" value="mysql"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword" value=""/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="mysql"/-->

           <!-- ENABLE THESE FOR ODF -->
           <!-- Change the "tutorial.ods" to include the path to your ODF file -->
           <!--property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="odf:file:tutorial.ods"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="odf"/-->

           <!-- ENABLE THESE FOR EXCEL -->
           <!-- Change the "tutorial.xls" to include the path to your Excel file -->
           <!--property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="excel:file:tutorial.xls"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="excel"/-->

           <!-- ENABLE THESE FOR MONGODB -->
           <!--property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="mongodb:/nucleus1"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="mongodb"/-->

           <!-- ENABLE THESE FOR HBASE -->
           <!--property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="hbase:"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="hbase"/-->

           <!-- ENABLE THESE FOR NEO4J -->
           <!-- Change the "testDB" to the path to your Neo4j graph DB file -->
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="neo4j:C:\Users\Sungjin\Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="neo4j"/>

           <!-- ENABLE THESE FOR CASSANDRA -->
           <!--property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="cassandra:"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.mapping.Schema" value="schema1"/>
           <property name="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="cassandra"/-->

           <property name="datanucleus.schema.autoCreateAll" value="true"/>
   ```

2. Edit the dependency jars for neo4j at pom.xml file

   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
       4.0.0
       org.datanucleus
       datanucleus-samples-jdo-tutorial
       jar
       5.0
       DataNucleus AccessPlatform Tutorial for JDO
       http://www.datanucleus.org

   ```
   <properties>
       <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
       <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
   </properties>

   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
           <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
           <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
           <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jdo</artifactId>
           <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
           <artifactId>javax.jdo</artifactId>
           <version>[3.2.0-m4, )</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>log4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
           <version>[1.2, 1.3)</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR H2 -->
       <!--<dependency>-->
           <!--<groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>-->
           <!--<artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>-->
           <!--<version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>-->
       <!--</dependency>-->
       <!--<dependency>-->
           <!--<groupId>com.h2database</groupId>-->
           <!--<artifactId>h2</artifactId>-->
           <!--<version>1.3.168</version>-->
       <!--</dependency>-->

       <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR HSQLDB -->
       <!--dependency>
           <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
           <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
           <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
           <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
           <version>1.8.0.4</version>
       </dependency-->

       <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR MYSQL -->
       <!--dependency>
           <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
           <artifactId>datanucleus-rdbms</artifactId>
           <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>mysql</groupId>
           <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
           <version>5.1.17</version>
       </dependency-->

       <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR ODF -->
       <!--dependency>
           <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
           <artifactId>datanucleus-odf</artifactId>
           <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.odftoolkit</groupId>
           <artifactId>odfdom-java</artifactId>
           <version>0.8.7</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>xerces</groupId>
           <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
           <version>[2.8, 3.0)</version>
       </dependency-->

       <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR EXCEL -->
       <!--dependency>
           <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
           <artifactId>datanucleus-excel</artifactId>
           <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
           <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
           <version>3.6</version>
       </dependency-->

       <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR MongoDB -->
       <!--dependency>
           <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
           <artifactId>datanucleus-mongodb</artifactId>
           <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
           <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.0</version>
       </dependency-->

       <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR HBase -->
       <!--dependency>
           <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
           <artifactId>datanucleus-hbase</artifactId>
           <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
           <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
           <version>1.1.2</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
           <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
           <version>1.1</version>
       </dependency-->

       <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR Neo4j -->
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
           <artifactId>datanucleus-neo4j</artifactId>
           <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
           <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
           <version>2.3.0</version>
       </dependency>

       <!-- ENABLE THIS FOR Cassandra -->
       <!--dependency>
           <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
           <artifactId>datanucleus-cassandra</artifactId>
           <version>[5.0.0-m1, 5.9)</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
           <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
           <version>2.1.4</version>
       </dependency-->
   </dependencies>

   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.5</version>
               <configuration>
                   <filesets>
                       <fileset>
                           <directory>${basedir}</directory>
                           <includes>
                               <include>*.log</include>
                               <include>tutorial.ods</include>
                               <include>tutorial.xls</include>
                           </includes>
                       </fileset>
                       <fileset>
                           <directory>${basedir}/testDB</directory>
                       </fileset>
                   </filesets>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.3.2</version>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
               <artifactId>datanucleus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>4.0.2</version>
               <configuration>
                   <api>JDO</api>
                   <persistenceUnitName>Tutorial</persistenceUnitName>
                   <log4jConfiguration>src/main/resources/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                   <verbose>false</verbose>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>compile</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>enhance</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <mainClass>org.datanucleus.samples.jdo.tutorial.Main</mainClass>
                   <systemProperties>
                       <systemProperty>
                           <key>log4j.configuration</key>
                           <value>file:src/main/resources/log4j.properties</value>
                       </systemProperty>
                   </systemProperties>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>2.2.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <descriptors>
                       <descriptor>${basedir}/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                   </descriptors>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
3. i ran Maven command mvn clean compile - success
4. mvn datanucleus:schema-create = error
5. mvn exec:java = error

in the Datanucleus Tutorial 5.0 Maven commands are different.

i also followed it .

3. mvn compile  = success
4. mvn datanucleus:enhance = success
5. mvn exec:java = error

i followed these steps and never touched other files.

did i done something wrong??

Comment: and i also tried added org.codehaus.mojo and maven-plugin:1.1 dependency on my pom.xml and ran again, but i had a same problem. T.T

Comment: why not post the real exception ... the one in the log? I run the tutorial and it works out of the box for me

Comment: thanks for your comment,  you mean InvocationTargetException? the one in the log?

Comment: InvocationTargetException ALWAYS wraps a cause exception. And this will almost certainly be in the DataNucleus log.

Comment: "exec-maven-plugin" v1.1 is in Maven central and always has been http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/ so how can it "fail to load"? You have Maven debug to debug such things. Consequently I don't get your "i exactly followed what tutorial said. ". You evidently haven't

Comment: The README tells you clearly enough that there are only 2 changes needed to run that. Edit pom.xml to ENABLE the neo4j part, and persistence.xml to comment out the RDBMS part and enable the neo4j part. No change to these sections is needed. I downloaded it and did just that ... and it worked. So you did something different

Comment: thanks to keep commenting on my question. wait i'll edit to add details of what i done.

Comment: So you didn't just do as the README then, as I said. You also EDITED the Neo4j URL for some reason. So that is the source of your problem. I simply edit as I said and run "mvn clean compile exec:java". That's it. Not hard

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH that it worked. i thought <----Change the "testDB" to the path to your Neo4j graph DB file---> in persistence..xml file means that change testDB to my Neo4j database path that created when starting neo4j. In README file, it says src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</a>   **[Edit the datastore details here]. So i thought i had to edit what persistence.xml file's annotation said. again, thank for your advices!!!:-)